# Why is my fetch() sending an empty JSON body?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, fetch, fetch-api

I've been trying to send a JSON data using fetch but the backend receives an empty object.
In my Client JS I have

```
const user = "company1";
const username = "muneeb";

const data = {user, username};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/api/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The server side has:

```
router.post('/users/api/login', async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
        // console.log(request.body);
        const request = JSON.stringify(req.body);

        let imageTitles = [];
        console.log(request);

        *its random from here on out but you get the idea*

        await components.getImages(imageTitles);
        const finalKey = imageTitles.join("");
        let images = await components.output(req.body.user ,req.body.username);
        res.send(components.jsonConverter(imageTitles, images)); //---Top priority
        db.setPassword(req.body.user, req.body.username , finalKey);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err).sendStatus(500);
    };
})
```

A few things I have already tried :

It works perfectly in Insomnia(postman).

express.json() is present , it helped me go from undefined to blank JSON.

I have enabled cors settings.

That's it for now.

Comment: I changed it, still no change . Thanks alot tho.

Comment: Have you checked the network monitor in your dev tools? Do you see the body in the request?

Comment: Yes I just did, it sends a post request promptly to the server, the server reads request and says its blank. The payload in the network monitor is the correct one.

Comment: Why do you stringify in the `fetch` call: `body: JSON.stringify(data)`? Try `body: data`

Comment: I tried it without ```JSON.stringify()```  and it still doesn't work. No significant changes found

Comment: @jabaa That's the normal way to send a JSON text body

Comment: @Bergi I confused it with Axios or jQuery. There you pass the object, not the JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body parser [`express.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) will only be applied for requests with `Content-Type: application/json`. You have to add the content type to your `fetch` call:

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/api/login", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```